# Vaadin 8: change background color of description (tooltip)

Tags: java, css, vaadin, vaadin8

I use Vaadin 8 and I need to change the background color of the tooltip (when it appeares) because it seems to be not readable...any idea ?

```
searchPanelBtn = new Button();
searchPanelBtn.setWidth(80, Unit.PIXELS);
searchPanelBtn.setIcon(VaadinIcons.CHEVRON_CIRCLE_LEFT_O);
// below the tooltip to change background color
searchPanelBtn.setDescription("Hide Panel");
```

Comment: please provide your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add this code in the styles.scss

```
.v-tooltip {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tatu it was simple... :-)